# how to get the data from infopath to sharepoint list?

Tags: infopath

I have two infopath forms "onboard" and "Offboard". I have published both the forms into one list. I have submitted with some data through onboard form. i do find the data what you have given in the form.How can i achieve this.

Comment: It seems your English is a little shaky (which is why I think someone gave you a -1)... Maybe if you rephrased your question a little it would help folks to understand better.  You should use question marks at the end of a sentence when you ask a question, like this:  How do I ask a question?

Answer (score 1):

If both of your forms are in the same library, you can just create a new "view" based on the "standard" view.  This view works just like a regular custom list, and you can pick and choose the columns to show.  In a forms library, the default view is the `All Documents` view, which, by default, shows the `filename`, `Modified`, `Modified By` and `Checked Out To`.  So you would want to create a new view.

Answer (score 0):

On InfoPath, you can see all list properties. This means you can reach OnBoard form items from OffBoard form and set OffBoard form items to OnBoard form items' data. You can use InfoPath rules to set form items data.